# Data accessing while database file size more than 4 GB

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sqlite, ormlite-servicestack

I am working on `ORMLite-ServiceStack`, `ASP.NET/C#` with a `SQLite Database`. I am facing the issue while accessing the data from Database file. The size of database file is 4.5 GB approximately.

I am trying to load the data by complex `Sql` query (atleast 6-7 million records in each table) by `ASP.NET` and using the `SQLiteDataReader` `ExecuteReader()`. The application hangs. In fact I am not able to run the `SQL` query via SQlite-Manager Firefox (Version 0.8.3.1) as well as GitHub `SQLite` browser. Both tool would become hang, I have to kill by task manager.

Please suggest any optimization tool or any configuration setting for SQLite database. So I can be able to access the data via web application or web service.

Comment: This is a pretty open-ended question.  Can you be more specific with the things you have already tried?

Comment: `atleast 6-7 million records in each table`, this much data on a client side DB ?? You will run into performance issues for sure, re-think/redesign what you are trying to do. This doesn't sound like something to be dealt with client side storage/db.

Comment: I have divided the long query in 2 parts. most of the query converted in database VIEW. Now I am just access the view by Where Select Query. If Database size is around 1 GB than all are working fine. as data is increasing that performance issue is facing. I am not using much Index.

Comment: This is the server side Data. Its not client side. Client side data in Android tablet and database size in MB. Mobile application transfer the data to Server (Service Stack App with Sqlite database) by JSON web service. My web base application display the same data in gridview (ASP.NET C#) by Filter and Limit

Comment: Are you trying to bring 2 million record to the android tablet? Are you trying to insert 2 million record to the db from the tablet? Is running the query or inserting data the problem? Im with Brian please be more specific on what is your problem. Show us a query or a code to see what are you trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

I believe SQLite normally have a 2GB limit, but apparently you went well beyond 2GB.

Here are the limitations of SQLite https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html

If your needs go beyond that, then you need to consider using a different database system like SQL Server.

Comment: The Maximum Database Size is approximately 1.4e+14 bytes (140 terabytes, or 128 tebibytes, or 140,000 gigabytes or 128,000 gibibytes). 
as per https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html

Comment: Are you reaching any of the other limits? It says SQLite is untested when going beyond a certain level. With 4.5GB, I still think SQLite may not be the best option. There are other database systems that are designed for large databases and will offer better performance and scalability, such as SQL Server or MySQL.

Comment: I am thinking to change the Database from SQlite to MySql as SQlite not good for Heavy Load and accessing by multiple client always show database locked error

Answer (score 0):

The best initial tweaks I would suggest would be to add composite indexes to each table containing any columns being queried (pretty sure only one index per table is used by SQLite in a single query). This will grow your db to an even larger size though, but should speed up your current scenario.

Comment: Yes I am using only the default index in Primay Key column.